# Server Streaming Project with Node Js

Tags: node.js, stream

I want to model a live digital television station with node js. I would have the media files playing on the server and have clients join in and watch in sync with what the server is showing. How can I achieve this with Node Js. The client could be with a web browser or an android application

Comment: The keyword here is `realtime`. Maybe `socket.io` is the way forward. you might want to explore some of the real world use cases for it.

Comment: They don't seem to provide a solution on it

Comment: @AjiboyeAdedeji did you manage to find a solution on this? I was thinking about WebRTC, but failed to convert DataStream from Node to MediaStream on client.